# Show current Username in angular Authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a login script already made by someone else. My aim was in fact to integrate the use of `ng-option` instead of the `input`. And this works, as you can see from the example. But when I logged in, I can not see the user's data. Why?

FULL CODE: http://plnkr.co/edit/ImsqhVFVanCp5OXNisrA?p=preview

Controllers.js:

```
angular.module('Authentication')

.controller('LoginController',
['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'AuthenticationService',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, AuthenticationService) {
    // reset login status
    AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
         $scope.users = [
                {"username": "test", "number": "13242342"},
                {"username": "2", "number": "00000000"},
                {"username": "3", "number": "0483184"},
            ];
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.dataLoading = true;
        AuthenticationService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password,        function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials($scope.username,     $scope.password);
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                $scope.error = response.message;
                $scope.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I do hope you realize that you can't do authorization in browser ... that all the login credentials are exposed in your script

Comment: Of course, I'm just doing some tests to learn better angular :D

Comment: Just checking... you see lots of weird misconceived ideas around here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your authentication service, you're setting the user's credentials like this:

```
$rootScope.globals = {
    currentUser: {
        username: username,
        authdata: authdata
    }
};
```

So in your view you need to change `{{user.username}}` to `{{globals.currentUser.username}}`.